# DRF - queryset filter using contains field lookup on SlugRelatedField

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I am struggling to figure out the how to run queryset filter using "field__contains" on a SlugRelatedField.
I have a simple Book model and a Tag model that looks as following:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
  publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
  publication_date = models.DateField()

class MetaTag(models.Model):
  book = models.ManyToManyField('Book', related_name='meta_tags',
  help_text='The book this meta tag belongs to')
  value = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True, help_text='Meta tag value')

class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class BookHyperlink(serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    """A Hyperlink field for book details"""

      def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        url_kwargs = {
            'pk': obj.id,
        }
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs=url_kwargs, request=request, format=format)
  url = BookHyperlink(view_name='book-detail')
  meta_tags = CreatableSlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='value', queryset=MetaTag.objects.all())

  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = (
        'id',
        'title',
        'publisher',
        'publication_date',
        'meta_tags',
        'url'
    )

class MetaTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = MetaTag
    fields = ('id', 'book', 'value',)

class CreatableSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):

  def to_internal_value(self, data):
    try:
        return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})[0]
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        self.fail('does_not_exist', slug_name=self.slug_field, value=smart_text(data))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        self.fail('invalid')

  class Meta:
    model = MetaTag
    fields = ('id', 'book', 'value', )
```

Now in my BooksView, I want to be able to filter the queryset by meta_tags value. I've tried the following with "__contains" field lookup:

```
class Books(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  """Default view for Book."""

  queryset = Book.objects.all()
  serializer_class = BookSerializer
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

  filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
  filter_fields = tuple(f.name for f in Book._meta.get_fields())

  def get_queryset(self):

    search_pattern = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
    if search_pattern is not None and search_pattern is not '':
        self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(meta_tags__contains = search_pattern)
    return self.queryset

def get_object(self):
    if self.kwargs.get('pk'):
        return Book.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

But I get the following error from django:

> File "~MyProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1076, in build_lookup
>       raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
>   django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains

Which as I understand means that since "meta_tags" is not a regular array or Text field, the contains field lookup cannot be applied on that field.

What is the best way if so to filter the queryset in such case for meta_tags value?

Answer (score 0):

A django expert I've consulted about this issue, suggested to try append the "slug_field" ("__value" in this case) to "__contains" field lookup when used with external model.

It was not documented anywhere or even on django official documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains, so I had no way to know it works this way, but this solution actually works:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(meta_tags__value__contains=search_pattern)
```

It actually makes sense when you look deeper at the MetaTag model, as "value" is the inner field of the meta_tags model:

```
class MetaTag(models.Model):

    book = models.ManyToManyField('Book', related_name='meta_tags',
                                 help_text='The book this meta tag belongs to')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True, help_text='Meta tag value')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s > %s' % (self.channel, self.value)
```

The reason it was not so obvious to append __value at the first place is because meta_tags array (array of objects) is flattened using the SlugRelatedField serializer where only the slug_field is projected and the rest fields are omitted.
So the final output of meta_tags array is flat:

```
meta_tags: ['tag1','tag2']
```

instead of:

```
meta_tags: [{book: 'a', value: 'tag1'},{book: 'a', value: 'tag2'}]
```

But since serialization on django DRF is made on a late stage (after queryset is completed) the original field schema should be considered.

Hope this will save somebody's headache someday.